# how to parse the XML file and search one particular string occurred using LabVIEW

Tags: labview

Im able to parse the XML but how to search one particular string and how many times it occured. And we need to parse so many files using this located in one folder

What i have tried till now looks like this [image: SearchRetry]

[image: XML Blocks]

[image: MainVI]

[image: User Output]

Comment: Is it necessary to actually parse the XML, since this is time consuming? Since XML is just text, a simple string search may be sufficient, unless there is somehing XML specific. If you need to parse the XML, are you looking for a tag / attribute / attribute value / value? Could you give an example in this case?

Comment: This sounds like a job for regex! But seriously, if you add some more detail (example XML, etc) I think we'll be able to help. I'm unsure if you're trying to only retrieve part of the XML or if you're trying to see how many times a string is part of different values in XML.

Comment: Please accept my apology for incomplete information.I'll describe in details now..

Comment: So this is what my XML file has : </PICTURE-BLOCK>

<DECISION Id="1055" Name="Launchconnectionretry" Verdict="Passed">Launch Widget:connect, retry count:0</DECISION>


+<TEXT-BLOCK Id="1056">


-<TEXT-BLOCK Id="1057">

<TEXT Font-Size="5" Color="#000000">File   so what i want is we have to search retry count =1 in whole XML file how many time it has been occurred. We will add counter and display it to user in form of Xcel file consisting:  File Name  Retry count. Yes agree with you i guess no need to parse XML file

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right path, though I see a few little details I would change. For example, you don't need to use the add node to add one since you can use the increment node instead.

I think I see one huge bug where you have = 0 in your top image. That should be >0 since you're looking for times when it failed.

I do think parsing the XML is the "right way" to do this, though in your particular application you might not be worrying about accidentally picking up this text string in other XML nodes.